# Merge multiple on<property>Changed events to one in QML

Tags: qml

I have created `Canvas` in QML, which have multiple properties. `Canvas` will draw something depending on those properties, and I want to use function `requestPaint` once (if some property/properties change), so I don't have to redraw `Canvas` multiple times.

Is there any way to merge multiple `onPropertyChanged` events into one?
Something, that will work like `if(onAChanged || onBChanged)`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you want to avoid calling `requestPaint` multiple times for performance considerations (like when 2 properties change at the same time, you'd like `requestPaint` to be called only once ?) or just to have a less verbose syntax ?

Comment: Actually: I have not made any tests on it, but I think it is not that terrible, to call `requestPaint` multiple times since a `requestPaint` is not equal to a `paint`. I don't know the algorithm that is used to decide when to draw, though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512689/qt-qml-canvas-requestpaint-does-not-repaint-immediately-the-scene

Comment: @GrecKo Avoid call it multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't merge multiple property change signals in one. This would be problematic for other things that depend on the signals.

However you might connect one function to multiple signals.

```
function doSomething() { ... }
onAChanged: doSomething()
onBChanged: doSomething()
```

You might also emit one signal:

```
signal someThingsChanged()
onAChanged: someThingsChanged()
onBChanged: someThingsChanged()
onSomeThingsChanged: { ... }
```

There is also the possibility to use [scripts] to automatically connect on function to multiple/all signals:

[Connect dynamically to signals of dynamically created objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121850/connect-dynamically-to-signals-of-dynamically-created-objects)

---

To avoid multiple calls of the slot, you might set a bool property like:

```
property bool dirty
```

and check it e.g. once per render cycle.

I think a Timer with `interval: 1` or the [`beforeRendering`-signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#beforeRendering) should do that job.

---

Most likely however, what you try to do, is unnecessary, since a `requestPaint` does not directly trigger a `paint` and the *collection* of those requests is already handled by the `Canvas`. As a proof, see this small example:

```
Timer {
    interval: 100
    running: true
    repeat: true
    onTriggered: {
        console.log('RequestPaint')
        cvs.requestPaint()
    }
}
Timer {
    interval: 100
    running: true
    repeat: true
    onTriggered: {
        console.log('RequestPaint')
        cvs.requestPaint()
    }
}
Timer {
    interval: 100
    running: true
    repeat: true
    onTriggered: {
        console.log('RequestPaint')
        cvs.requestPaint()
    }
}

Canvas {
    id: cvs
    width: 100
    height: 100
    onPainted: console.log('Painted')
    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 1);
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

The three Timers all call `requestPaint` but `onPainted` is only called once.

> ```
> qml: RequestPaint
> qml: RequestPaint
> qml: RequestPaint
> qml: Painted
> qml: RequestPaint
> qml: RequestPaint
> qml: RequestPaint
> qml: Painted
> ```

Comment: But if I call `onSomeThingsChanged: { canvas.requestPaint() }`, it will still be called twice and be painted twice, am I right?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help, i will do timer solution

Comment: @derM 
the use of the Timer smells me ugly, you are spending resources unnecessarily. :)

Comment: @eyllanesc: You are right since `requestPaint` handles that stuff already.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to do an action when multiple properties are changed, but don't want to call the action multiple times when multiple properties are called at one, you can use [`Qt.callLater(function)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#callLater-method).
It will call the function only once at the next event loop tick.

```
function someFunction() { /* ... */ }
onPropAChanged: Qt.callLater(someFunction)
onPropBChanged: Qt.callLater(someFunction)
```

However in your case, it's actually not needed. `requestPaint` doesn't direclty cause a painting of the `Canvas`, it just informs the scene graph that it needs to be repainted. Calling it multiple time at onces will results in only one repainting of your canvas. You can verify that by printing something to the console on the `onDraw` of your canvas.

Comment: `Qt.callLater` is buggy sometimes. I don't know whether the bug has an impact here.

Comment: Good to know. It shouldn't have an impact here since it's not needed ;)